# How to add OrderBy clause in multi-table LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

This is my LINQ query with lambda expression which works fine:

```
var query = this.context.Blocks.Where(o => 
    o.IsActive && o.ProductSizes.Any(x => 
        x.SectionProductSizes.Any(y => 
            && y.SectionID == queryCriteria.SectionId y.Section.SizeTypeID == o.SizeTypeID
        )
    )
);
```

How can we add sorting on DisplayOrder column within SectionProductSizes table?

Adding model classes used for this:

```
public partial class Blocks
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SizeTypeID { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductSize
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ProductSizeID { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SectionProductSize> SectionProductSizes { get; set; }
}

public partial class SectionProductSize
{
    public int SectionProductSizeID { get; set; }
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public int ProductSizeID { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int SizeTypeID { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add your model classes also

Comment: Your block may contain many `ProductSize` and those in their turn may contain many `SectionProductSize`, how do you determine by which to make the order?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer this question without seeing your Model, but from what you have provided the following should hopefully work.

```
var query = this.context.Blocks.Where(o =>
                        o.IsActive && o.ProductSizes.Any(x =>
                        x.SectionProductSizes.Any(y =>
                        && y.SectionID == queryCriteria.SectionId y.Section.SizeTypeID == o.SizeTypeID
                        )
                      )
                    ).OrderBy(x => x.SectionProductSizes.DisplayOrder);
```

Comment: Added model classes used for LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by converting lambda expression query to normal LINQ query:

```
        var query = from bl in this.dbContext.Blocks
                    join ps in this.dbContext.ProductSizes on bl.Id equals ps.ModularContentBlockID
                    join sp in this.dbContext.SectionProductSizes on ps.Id equals sp.ProductSizeID
                    join se in this.dbContext.Sections on sp.SectionID equals se.Id
                    where bl.IsActive 
                        && se.SectionSizeTypeID == bl.SectionSizeTypeID
                        && sp.SectionID == queryCriteria.SectionId 
                    orderby sp.DisplayOrder
                    select bl;
```